# Misinterpretation of the @ key with LogMeIn on a Mac

Tags: mac, remote, logmein

I'm trying to use LogMeIn on a Mac to work remotely with a PC host.
However, when I press *@* on my Mac keyboard, it somehow translates to *"* on the PC host. What could cause this?

Comment: What happens if you type `"`?

Answer (score 0):

Many keyboard layouts are different for Macs and PCs. For example shift+2 is " on the PC UK layout and @ on the Mac UK layout.

If you meant to use some other layout on Windows, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258824.

http://kb.parallels.com/en/113541 linked to this [Mac UK layout for Windows](http://www.parkernet.com/applepro/index.html).

You could also use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<only>VIRTUALMACHINE</only>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_2, VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::QUOTE, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
```

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Another option might be to switch to the US layout. It has all ASCII characters in the same positions on Mac and Windows.